# Getting error "this cannot be used in constant expression" at bool ar[V];

Tags: c++, arrays

```
class A{
    int V;
public:
    bool function(){
        bool ar[V];
    }
}
```

i am getting an 'this cannot be used in a constant expression' error at the V variable :bool ar[V];

Comment: C++ doesn't have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). Array sizes must be compile-time constants. If the size is only known at run-time use `std::vector`.

Comment: [Why aren't variable-length arrays part of the C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/)